# Django: What is the correct way to query by foreign key field's id?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two `models`:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Folder(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey("Organization",related_name='folders')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Now I want to filter the `folder` by `organization id`. so I tried:

- `Folder.objects.filter(organization= 1)`
- `Folder.objects.filter(organization_id= 1)`
- `Folder.objects.filter(organization__id= 1)`
- `Folder.objects.filter(organization__pk= 1)`
- `Folder.objects.filter(organization= Organization.objects.get(id=1))`

Believe it or not everything returns the same.

So anybody know what is the correct way to query by foreign key field's id?

### update

but when try to create `folder` by:

```
Folder.objects.create(organization__id=1,title='hello')
```

got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/suhail/.virtualenvs/heybadges/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/suhail/.virtualenvs/heybadges/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 370, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/home/suhail/.virtualenvs/heybadges/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 452, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'organization__id' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

but `Folder.objects.create(organization_id=1,title='hello')` works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut) say that you should use `Folder.objects.filter(organization__pk=1)` in most cases.

Comment: i am sorry but the `create` function has problem with `organization__id`,any idea why this happed?

Comment: Where does it say in that doc that this is the recommended way? I think it only shows that it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to the update:

Probably `Folder.objects.create(organization_id=1,title='hello')` works because [Django appends "_id" to the field name to create its database column name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#database-representation).