# Django filtering objects from a filtered foreignkey object

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to filter a list of lectures which have a foreignkey relation with a model called content. Basically every lecture is related to a specific content. But I'm stuck. below is my code:

models.py

```
class CourseContent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class CourseLecture(models.Model):
    content = models.ForeignKey(CourseContent, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    file = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def coursedetails(request, pk):
    course = Course.objects.get(id = pk)
    content = CourseContent.objects.filter(course = course)
    content_ids = content.values_list('id')
    lectures = CourseLecture.objects.filter(content__in = content_ids)
    reviews = course.review_set.all()
    rev_count = reviews.count()
    avg = reviews.aggregate(avg = Avg('rating'))
    total = reviews.aggregate(sum = Sum('rating'))
    print(content_ids)
    return render(request, "main/course_detail_view.html", {"course": course, "lectures": lectures, "content": content , "reviews": reviews, "rev_count": rev_count, "avg": avg, "total": total})
```

The problem here is that i cannot filter lectures on basis of specific content ids. The objects filtered is showing in all the content rather than showing in their specific section.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above implementation should work, but it is not efficient. Here is how I would do:

```
lectures = CourseLecture.objects.filter(content__course_id = pk)
```

If you mean to order the lectures by content_id, then just add `order_by`:

```
lectures = CourseLecture.objects.filter(content__course_id = pk).order_by('content')
```

Finally, if you want to show the lectures respect to each content, then probably use the following template code:

```
{% for c in content %}
    {{ c.title }}
    {% for lecture in c.courselecture_set.all %}
       {{ lecture.title }}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and replace the line with

```
lectures = CourseLecture.objects.filter(content__pk__in = content_ids)
```

Refer this [Django: What is the correct way to query by foreign key field's id?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29673059/5404694) for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `related_name` in your Foreign Key.
So, it will be like:

then you can just use `Course.lecture.all()`. And it will give you all of the lectures with that Course Foreign Key.

Eg:

```
class Airport(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=4)

class Flights(models.Model):
    origin = models.ForeignKey(Airport, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="origin")
    destination= models.ForeignKey(Airport, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="destination")
    duration = models.IntegerField()
```

So, `Airport.objects.get(pk=1).origin.all()` will give me all Flights that Originate from Airport with Primary Key 1.

Hope this Helps.