# Django admin - Allow inline entires once selected item

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I am trying to populate a dropdown in the Django admin panel based on a selected item.

I have a customer model

```
class Customer(BaseModel):
name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
company = models.ForeignKey("Company", models.PROTECT)


def __str__(self) -> str:
    return f"{self.name}"

def save(self, **kwargs):
    return super().save(**kwargs)
```

An invite model

```
class Invite(BaseModel):
full_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
email = WIEmailField(unique=True)
customer = models.ForeignKey(
    to="Customer",
    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    related_name="invites",
)
```

Customer Invite model that defines the invite and customer

```
class CustomerLocationInvite(BaseModel):
location = models.ForeignKey(
    to=Location
)
invite = models.ForeignKey(
    to=Invite,
    blank=True,
)
```

Location Model

```
class Location(BaseModel):
name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
company = models.ForeignKey(
    to= Company,
    on_delete=models.PROTECT
)
address = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Inline for invite

```
class CustomerInviteInline(admin.TabularInline):
model = CustomerLocationInvite
fields = ("invite", "location", "created_at", "modified_at")
readonly_fields = ("created_at", "modified_at")
extra = 0
```

When creating a new Invite, Is it possible to:

1. Display the inline once a company has been selected?
2. When selecting a location from the inline, Filter out the locations based on the company they selected?

Comment: Can you also post the location model?

Comment: @crimsonpython24 Sure, just added it

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume you want to get the location from `CustomerLocationInvite`, and get the company from the location? If that is so, maybe you can try

```py
CustomerLocationInvite.objects.filter(location__id=locationid)
```

Where the location's id can be received by

```py
locationid = Location.objects.filter(company__id=companyid).id
```

But then since you said that the company is already selected, you should have its ID -- that is the value you will replace `companyid` with. You can then retrieve the inline admin from the `CustomerLocationInvite` object that you received in the first line.

[SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672793/django-what-is-the-correct-way-to-query-by-foreign-key-fields-id)
[Doc reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut)

2. I'm not sure what you mean. Are you getting the list of companies, or are you getting the list of locations? That being said, please paste your `Company` model as well.